# Counting in a multiquery

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

this is the query I'm using to display a list over popular crimes, aswell as the users with most of the crimes.

```
SELECT * ,
(
    SELECT p.Username
    FROM crimes AS sc
    INNER JOIN players AS p ON p.ID = sc.crimeIssuedTo
    WHERE sc.crimeDescription = sm.crimeDescription
    GROUP BY sc.crimeIssuedTo
    ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) AS PersonWithMostOffenses, 

(
    SELECT p.Username
    FROM crimes AS sc
    INNER JOIN players AS p ON p.ID = sc.crimeIssuer
    WHERE sc.crimeDescription = sm.crimeDescription
    GROUP BY sc.crimeIssuer
    ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) AS PersonWithMostIssues




FROM crimes AS sm
GROUP BY sm.crimeDescription
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

Here's the results:

```
crimeID | crimeIssuer   | crimeIssuedTo | crimeDescription  | crimeIssuerName   | crimeIssuedToName | PersonWithMostOffences    | PersonWithMostIssues
2   | 59459     | 59464     | Grand Theft       | Cop_Name      | Criminal_Name     | Criminal_Name         | CopName
```

But I'd also like to add MostOffencesCount and MostIssuesCount. How can I put that into this query?